# Поменять местами элементы массива

Tags: java

Как поменять элементы массива местами и вывести их в столбик? Пользователь сам вводит числа в массив, неопределенное количество
Допустим пользователь ввел 4 числа, т.е массив длиной в 4 элемента
По заданию элементы должны меняться местами, по такой схеме
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 3 2 1
Никак не могу понять как это сделать. Написал код только до того момента, где нужно ввести элементы

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите длину массива: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        int [] array = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Введите элементы массива: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();
        String one = Arrays.toString(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: В этой системе нет закономерности. Для 4 чисел, допустим, понятно, четко по вашей схеме переставляем. А если чисел 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//int[] result = new int[size * size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    //result[i * size + j] = array[(i + j) % size];
    System.out.print(array[(i + j) % size]);
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а вы могли бы в деталях написать что делает строчка System.out.print(array[(i + j) % size]);?

Comment: @LoopEx Я-то мог бы ). Попробуйте Вы. Оператор `%` называется "остаток от деления на".

Comment: Все, я разобрался, спасибо за помощь, я просто тугодум :)

Comment: @LoopEx Это главное - что Вы сами выстроили у себя в голове логику кода. Успехов!